Go + Postgres : pq unexpected Parse response 'C' with QueryRow
I'm facing the error unexpected Parse response 'C' and searching on the internet I found out this error happens when rows are not closed after the previous query.
But in my case I'm only using QueryRow which return a *sql.Row where Close isn't implemented.
type Queryable interface {
    QueryRow(query string, args ...interface{}) *sql.Row
}

func GetOrCreateArticle(q Queryable, article *entity.Article) (id int64, err error) {
    const selectQuery string = "SELECT id FROM articles WHERE link = $1"
    const insertQuery string = "INSERT INTO articles (link, title) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id"

    err = q.QueryRow(selectQuery, article.Link).Scan(&id)
    fmt.Println("Error :", err, article.Link)

    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return id, q.QueryRow(insertQuery, article.Link, article.Title).Scan(&id)
    }

    return id, err
}

Queryable is an interface to represent either a *sql.DB or *sql.Tx, here the function is always call with a Transaction.
In the same transaction I'm querying / inserting multiple Articles, the first call to this function always ends with the expeted result while the second always throw the error : pq : unexpected Parse response 'C'.

Are you running the queries concurrently? That doesn't work with transactions.

I don't think so, but when I call this function with the *sql.DB instead of inside a transaction it ends with the error : pq: sorry, too many clients already (after around 100 articles) so maybe I'm missing something and my queries are running concurrently...

That sure sounds like you're not closing rows somewhere. I suggest you double check this.

How many instances of *sql.DB are you spawning?

You do know that an application generally needs only one *sql.DB instance, right?

@mkopriva I'm only using one instance of *sql.DB
@peter I don't deal with any *sql.Rows as I only use QueryRow which return a *sql.Row where no Close function are implemented

"I only use QueryRow which return a *sql.Row" -- @nem0z do you use QueryRow in your app without calling Scan? Perhaps you are using it somewhere for DELETE or UPDATE or INSERT queries (but without the RETURNING clause)? Note that *sql.Row has an internal reference to an *sql.Rows instance which is Rows.Closed when Row.Scan is called.

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/sql.go#L3488

And btw. *sql.Tx instances need to also be "closed" by calling either Commit or Rollback. If you don't do that in a timely fashion, then you'll be running out of available connections just the same.

Ultimately it's difficult to provide a precise diagnosis without seeing all the DB related code of your program. That's also is why it's recommended on SO to supplement your question with a [mcve], which helps in pinpointing the real cause of the issue.

The correct solution (at least in my case) wass to avoid combining async with database transactions. Transactions do not support running queries asynchronously. If you want to run I/O operations concurrently, I suggest getting rid of the transaction.
